# Remove some borders from Bootstrap .nav-tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I'm using Boostrap v3's .nav-tabs class to make tabbed menu.
In the attached pictures, I have marked in yellow the borders that I want to be removed.
I've tried many CSS selectors, but couldn't do it.

[image]

[image]
Does anyone know the way?

Comment: What does your code look like? Namely, are you loading your custom css after your bootstrap code?

Comment: Can we see the HTML code ?

Comment: My HTML code is way too complicated, but I got what I wanted from the accepted answer. Thanks anyway for your effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the custom css (ex: custom.css) after your bootstrap css file:

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the selector I was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 4 / this will remove all borders.

```
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: The question specifies bootstrap 3 - but if you're going to remove borders in bootstrap 4, use the built in [border utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/) like `border-0`.

Comment: I searched sepecifically
```nav tabs bootstrap 4 remove border```
 and this is the only thing that i found. It can be helpfull anyway.

```border-0``` looks betther. Thanks